# Hafele–Keating Experiment. What are the forces acting on the moving clock?

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics, time-dilation

According to the Hafele–Keating  Experiment, time dilation is the reason for the differences between the earth bound clock and the moving clock.

```
"General relativity predicts an additional effect, in which an increase in gravitational potential due to altitude speeds the clocks up. That is, clocks at higher altitude tick faster than clocks on Earth's surface."
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment

How does this “time dilation” manifest itself as a force to physically change the tick rate of the moving clock?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time dilation isn't a force, and moving clocks always tick at 1 tick per second. However, the "moving" clock and "stationary" clock take different paths through spacetime. This is why they end up showing different values when they are compared -- the clock measures the total elapsed spacetime "distance" (the proper time along the path the clock takes). The analogy is that a clock is like an odometer -- two cars which take different paths through space end up with different readings, just as two clocks which take different paths through spacetime end up with different readings too.

Comment: but if I sit beside moving clock, I would experience time in a normal fashion, ie 1 tick per second. So how can the moving clock have a different value when you take it out of the plane and sit it beside the stationary clock after the journey? Pardon my ignorance!

Comment: If you're moving alongside the clock, both you and the clock take a "longer" path through spacetime than a stationary clock and observer. (I put "longer" in quotes because the sign of time is opposite that of space, so the "longer" time actually corresponds to a shorter elapsed time), Neither you nor the clock notice anything unusual. Time is relative: there is no single universal time, and every clock actually measures its own unique path through spacetime. It just happens that in everyday life all of those paths have lengths that are so close we don't notice the difference.

Comment: @shoggananna Eric Smith's odometer analogy is an excellent one. If you and I take separate cars and drive in parallel down the highway, you may look over at my car and see that my odometer is registering 1 km for each km you drive. But if you park and I loop around town, my odometer will be changing while yours doesn't, so the relationship is different.

Comment: @Eric Smith: ok,  Maybe if I visualized theoretically the plane moving close to the speed of light away from earth and then returning, then somehow I can understand how my clock would read different to the stationary clock because of the effect of length contraction between me and the earth and therefore resulting in a shorter elapsed time wrt to the stationary clock? SO difficult to wrap my head around this.

Comment: No, it's not space contraction that makes the clocks read differently (although that contributes a little bit), it's mainly time dilation. Time is relative. There's no single absolute time. Every clock that moves relative to us is moving in a different direction in spacetime, not just space, which means that from our perspective each tick of the "moving" clock includes not only some time but also some space.

Comment: @Eric Smith: For all observers with their own reference frame, does time always tick "normally" even in extreme gravity fields like near black holes?

Comment: Yes, every clock always ticks normally for an observer at rest next to it (we're talking about ideal clocks here, of course!). The same clock however may disagree with distant clocks (in a different gravitational potential) and/or clocks that are moving relative to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple if you think in terms of a spacetime diagram. As an over-simplified version of the experiment, suppose there is an experimenter on an aircraft whose path is designed to follow that of an inertial motion, whose worldline is a timelike geodesic, and then there is a person on earth whose worldline is some spiral due to the rotation of the earth. Secondly, the *arclength* between two events $p_1$ and $p_2$ of an observer's worldline is their proper time: $\tau _2-\tau_1 = \int_{p_1}^{p_2}\sqrt{-ds^2}$, which is recorded by a standard clock that the observer carries. The proper time is exactly the internal aging experienced by an observer, and for the same observer it is always ticked away at the same rate, so there is no "force" influencing the clock rate (on the other hand, time dilation has to do with how one compares two clock readings on two worldlines in accordance with some choice of simultaneity). In all "twins paradox" situations, what is being compared are the two proper time readings that elapsed between two events. Because the plane's worldline is a timelike geodesic, the arclength of the plane's worldline between when it took off and when it lands is maximized, while the arclength of the worldline of the person on the ground between the same two events must always be smaller -- The plane experiences greater aging. So, once the plane lands, the one who went on the plane would have aged ever so slightly more than the one who stayed on the ground.